# Black shape only visible in Cycles Renderer, can't see it in any other viewmodes

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, gpu, render-passes

[image]Whenever I render my scene I see this unknown black shape on the renders. I can't figure out why because it doesn't seem to exist in any other viewmodes.

Comment: Do you have an object in the scene which is disabled for _Viewport_ but enabled for _Render_ (see the icons right to objects in the Outliner)?

Answer (score 0):

Been trying to solve it for such a long time, and just after asking this I just found out the solution... Seems like it gets fixed if I just change my render Device to GPU compute.

Comment: Switching from CPU to GPU did the trick? To me, the left side looks like you have chosen   _Eevee_ as _Render Engine_, or if it is really set to _Cycles_ then it seems to be _Material Preview_ shading mode (which uses _Eevee_ as well), not _Rendered_. And _Eevee_ does not show transparency by default, you have to change the _Blend Mode_.